# C usual arithmetic conversions and possible data loss warnings

Tags: c

In the code below VS and GCC both generate a "possible data loss" warning for the first assignment to s but not the second and I'm wondering why.  My understanding is that the (short)i operands will all be implicitly converted to type int prior to the multiplication and in both cases and the product will be type int.  Thus, the assignment of an int to a short will occur in both cases and both should cause (or not cause) a warning.  I believe I've heard that the standards don't require compilers to generate warnings at all, but this seems a little inconsistent.

```
int main(void)
{
   int i;
   short s;
   s = i * (short)i;
   s = (short)i * (short)i;
}
```

Comment: Would you expect a warning from `int i, j; j = i * i;`  or from `short i, j; j = i * i;` (apart from uninitialised values) where the product can exceed the range? In your second case you have effectively silenced the compiler.

Comment: @WeatherVane - I can certainly see how (short)(i * i) would silence the compiler because it produces a type short right operand, but doesn't (short)i * (short)i produce type int?  I don't expect a warning in short i, j; j = i * i; simply because in my experience compilers don't tend to generate data loss warnings in declaration initializations for some reason.

Comment: It does promote to `int`. I was trying to say that your `s = (short)i * (short)i;` is equivalent to `short j; s = j * j;` where you would not expect a warning.

Comment: @WeatherVane - As you indicated, I declared j as short and then did s = j * j; and did not get a warning, but I don't understand why not since the type of j * j is int and it is being assigned to a type short variable.  I obviously incorrectly "assumed" the compiler blindly looks at the type of the left operand and generates a warning if it cannot represent at least the same value range as the type of the right operand.  Could you perhaps point me to what I missed in the language standard regarding what it actually does in this case, or is it just a compiler preference?

Comment: Because you cast the `int` to `short`. You told the compiler to first convert `int` to `short`, and from there on you are multiplying `short` (which in both cases is promoted back to `int`). You don't get a warning when you perform `short = short * short`, whether it is from `short` variables, or from larger types that you explictly cast to `short`.